# Get HTTP Request header information : Java

Tags: java, spring, httprequest

This is my simple Spring Rest Controller.

How can I get the Http request header information every time an URL is mapped to my controller?

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name") String name) {

     // Here is where I want to get HTTP Request Header Info

    return null;     
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `@RequestHeader` as one of the arguments to the method to access it, e.g.:

```
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name") String name,
     @RequestHeader("Content-type") String contentType) {
```

[Here's](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestHeader.html) the javadoc for `@RequestHeader`.